# Custom Google Sign In throw exception on GIDSignInDelegate protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, google-signin

I'm writing an iOS app in obj-c and using Google SignIn SDK to do the Google SignIn flow. I wanna be able to customize the button and action a little it so I went ahead implementing the protocols of `GIDSignInDelegate` myself based on their documentation. But it throws and exception for no reason.

Here's the minimal code of my view controller.
`viewcontroller.m`

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>

    @interface ViewController ()


    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *GoogleSignIn;

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    - (IBAction)googleButtonTouchUpInside:(id)sender {
        [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
    }

    // Implement these methods only if the GIDSignInUIDelegate is not a subclass of
    // UIViewController.

    // Stop the UIActivityIndicatorView animation that was started when the user
    // pressed the Sign In button
    - (void)signInWillDispatch:(GIDSignIn *)signIn error:(NSError *)error {
        //[UIActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    }

    // Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google
    - (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
    presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    // Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view
    - (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
    dismissViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

`viewcontroller.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Google/SignIn.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <GIDSignInUIDelegate>

@end
```

I do have whatever delegate method is required for a custom login flow [google doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in)
Did I miss anything?

Comment: `signin.uiDelegate = self;` is missing I think ... but without posting your error ... I am not sure about it

Comment: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'uiDelegate must either be a |UIViewController| or implement the |signIn:presentViewController:| and |signIn:dismissViewController:| methods from |GIDSignInUIDelegate|.'
`
the error message says either do `sigin.uiDelegate = self` or implement delegate method by yourself?

Comment: In your button action  try... .`GIDSignIn *signin = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
    signin.shouldFetchBasicProfile = true;
    signin.uiDelegate = self;
    [signin signIn];`

Comment: this would prevent exceptions but won't initiate any Google Login View anymore..thanks for the help though.

Comment: now it says:
`
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController signIn:didSignInForUser:withError:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb4d947a850'
`

`    signIn.delegate = self;` will give incompatible type warning..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is basic workaround for google signIn ... so check what is missing for you

First of all in your button action use

```
GIDSignIn *signin = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
signin.shouldFetchBasicProfile = true;
signin.delegate = self;
signin.uiDelegate = self;
[signin signIn];
```

Then for Delegates

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {
    // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
    if (error == nil) {
        NSString *userId = user.userID;                  
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}

- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didDisconnectWithUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {
    // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
}

- (void)signInWillDispatch:(GIDSignIn *)signIn error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
}

// Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    //present view controller
}

// Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn dismissViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
      //dismiss view controller
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I did use your solution and checked others' post. at this moment, I'm not getting any exceptions any more. But the login view is not presented by my viewcontroller either. the button basically dose nothing...I have no clue where's the bug.

Comment: Thanks alot. i was struggling with google login and you saved me.

Comment: Thanks. I was creating ReactNative custom library and facing this issue. Thanks a log

Answer (score 5):

**Updated for Swift 3:**

used below lines of code in **signIn Button Action Method**:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

> Note: Comments above lines of code if you are using it anywhere in
>   your ViewController...! otherwise it will be fine.