# google signin and present view controller swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

Google sign in flow is abit odd to me and I am not sure how I can perform  the segue to display the VC that I wanted.

I have followed the google sign in documentation and the flow goes like this

1. When I click on the google button and login with my google account, the following gets called from my LoginVC

   ```
   func signInWillDispatch(signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: NSError!) {
   ```
2. Then the following function gets called in the app delegate

   ```
   // Google signin
   func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {

       if let error = error {
           print(error.localizedDescription)
           return
       }

       let authentication = user.authentication
       let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credentialWithIDToken(authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

       FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
       if let error = error {
           print("Error Signing in google")
       } else {
           print("Google signin successfully \(user?.email)")

       }
   }
   ```

   This is where I can retrieve the user data. I want to be able to display a detail view controller after I retrieved all the data I wanted from the user. However, I cant really do that from app delegate.

Also, there are two other default google functions in my LoginVC that does not get called and I am not sure how to have it called. I believe these two function might be the solution to what I wanted?

```
 func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {

 func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismissViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
```

Thanks,

Comment: check this ... may be you find any solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539531/custom-google-sign-in-throw-exception-on-gidsignindelegate-protocol/38539698#38539698

Answer (score 0):

> This is where I can retrieve the user data. I want to be able to
>   display a detail view controller after I retrieved all the data I
>   wanted from the user. However, I cant really do that from app
>   delegate.

You can actually get do whatever you want with the data and show your view controller.

Once you have received all the required data in app delegate, pass the data in NSNotification to the base controller from where you will push or present the detail view controller and you can use the data that you passed from NSNotification.

**Steps:**

1. **Post a notification from app delegate along with the data received
   from google's call back.**
2. **Add the listener to the base class from where you will push or present the detail view.**
3. **In the base class's listener's function call, retrieve the data passed from app delegate object and use it to push or present the detail view controller.**